# How to render text diffs with human readable difference highlighting in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, diff

I need to print inline diffs of text (code) in a human readable formatting (eg: not machine optimised).

My platform is Javascript (primary node.js, browser). I have my own printer/styler, but have problems generating the correct diff changes.

What is important is human intuitive changes: so a strong bias to changes per line, and very low on random fragmented letters.

Examples of non-JS diff renderers that look good are the one in Tortoise SVN/GIT and the diff renderer on github.com. I believe the one on github reads a 'standard' patch format, but I'm sure there is some more logic involved to turn that into a pretty inline diff.

Some modules I tried:

1. `diff` (https://npmjs.org/package/diff) classic but it has unnatural mix of line- and word- or character- diffs. (this is used in `mocha` but it is flawed)
2. `chardiff` (https://npmjs.org/package/chardiff) which is based on `diff`, but it has a semantic filter designed for human readability: it looks better but still gives fragmented single-letter changes (where classic diff wont).
3. `diff-match-patch` (http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch), which is promising but still not quite 100% (still some counter-intuitive differences).

I think I need to assemble something myself using one of these modules as component (per line etc), but I am unsure how to do it.

Is this a solved problem?

Comment: I know it's pretty late but i have developed an approach which seems to work well and very fast. For your future reference please have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/133849/105433